# Users get subscribed to the same list more than once

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I have developed a timerjob for MOSS 2007 which loops through a variety of subsites and then loops through all users on each site.

[Code can be seen here](http://pastebin.com/WY4VDm3N)

The issue at hand is that some of the users get multiple alert subscriptions on the same list, which shouldn't be possible as I check if any alerts on the current web contains both the user ID and list ID then that user should just be skipped.

All users are AD users and are members of AD groups which gets imported to SharePoint on a regular basis.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to guess :-)
Users got the multiple alert subscriptions on the `SPList discussion` list, didn't they? :-) :-) :-)
'Copy-past' is terrible thing.